# Can I have multiple PWAs on the same domain under different URL paths?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

For example, can I create a PWA under `example.com/todo-app`, another one under `example.com/time-tracking-app`, and have each as a completely separate app that can be "installed" with a different icon on the home screen, have its own separate notifications, etc.?

Comment: Have you gone through this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028343/pwa-with-multiple-pages)?

Comment: It seems unrelated. They are talking about a single app with multiple pages. I want to host many separate apps on a single domain, separated by URL path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it if each separate PWA has:

- a link to a different manifest
- uses Service Workers that have non-overlapping scopes. That means you have to register them with scopes that look something like `navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {scope: './todo-app/'})` and `navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {scope: './time-tracking-app/'})`

In general I'd advise against doing this because if you make any mistakes later on with scopes you'll have issues that will be very hard to debug.

Comment: I think the SW approach is necessary, specially because probably might need different push notification icons, and app names. So probably different cache files so different SW workers makes sense. Otherwise a single manifest could also work depends the complexity and requirements of the apps.

Answer (score 1):

Doing as you say has a different behavior.

I have both the WebPWAs installed on the home screen. However, when I click on both of the icons, both of them opens the PWA which was installed FIRST and ignores the target url.