# Multiple installable PWA in same base URL

Tags: mobile, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a PWA and I wanna know if it's possible to build an installable PWA that has many different routes, but each route being a different installable PWA.

Sample:

- `a.com/customer1` be a installable PWA for customer 1 (their "tenant")
- `a.com/customer2` be a installable PWA for customer 2 (their own tenant, different from customer 1 tenant)

Is this possible or I need to use different base URLs? If doesn't, maybe can I use subdomains?

Something like this:

`customer1.a.com` be one PWA, and `customer2.a.com` be another one.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486756/can-i-have-multiple-pwas-on-the-same-domain-under-different-url-paths

Comment: @Mathias in this post, they are different apps in different subroutes. In my question, they are the same app, the same project, just different subroutes in the same app.