# How to show the install button for a PWA

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps

Currently I implemented a site.webmanifest and a service worker on my new version of my blog.

https://nextjs.marcofranssen.nl/

Despite Lighthouse reports I'm 100% matching the PWA requirements, including installability, I do not see the install button in the address bar of my browser.

On my current version of my blog it does show up.

https://marcofranssen.nl

Following picture shows the button when navigating to my current blog.

[image: Install button PWA]

Now I'm wondering which requirement I'm missing.

I also did a review of this criteria https://web.dev/install-criteria/.

Does anybody have a clue what I'm missing or overreading?

See here for the manifest file https://nextjs.marcofranssen.nl/site.webmanifest

This manifest file is also referenced in the head section.

My old blog is fully static generated html. My new blog is build using Next.js so not entirely a static page, although I don't think that should matter.

Comment: So you have multiple PWAs at the same domain? This thread may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486756/can-i-have-multiple-pwas-on-the-same-domain-under-different-url-paths/47497026#:~:text=You%20can%20do%20it%20if,that%20look%20something%20like%20navigator.

Comment: @Mathias It is a different subdomain, so this should not be related to the paths discussed in that thread you are sharing.

Comment: I just tried, and I see the install icon appear, but it sometimes takes a moment or two. Chrome waits until the service worker is installed, and it has retrieved and validated the web app manifest. Try opening DevTools, and going to the Application Tab, then the Service Worker panel, and look to see if the service worker has completed its installation. If it hasn't give it a moment or two and see if it appears once the SW has completed its installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Despite Lighthouse reports I'm 100% matching the PWA requirements, including installability, I do not see the install button in the address bar of my browser.

I ran a lighthouse test on https://nextjs.marcofranssen.nl/ and [PWA] section had a few problems

[image: lighthouse test of https://nextjs.marcofranssen.nl/]

as detailed above, your website manifest misses `start_url` :

```
"name": "Marco Franssen - Blog",
"short_name": "MF Blog",
"description": "Blog by Marco Franssen, covering software development!",
"icons": [],
"theme_color": "#000000",
"background_color": "#ffffff",
"display": "standalone",
"start_url": "/"
}
```

for more details about manifest structure please refer to [Web app manifests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)

after that you need to implement a [serviceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Offline_Service_workers), and for that you can use [next-pwa package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-pwa) or [next-offline package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-offline) and both use [google's workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) under the hood.

I prefer [next-pwa package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-pwa), because it works out of the box and there is no need for too much configurations.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it and reported a bug with lighthouse. For me it was giving me a full green report. That is why I over read I missed the start url. I'm using next-pwa as well.

Comment: happy to help :)